# High fluctuation data optimisation and prediction

Tags: python, random, mathematical-optimization, prediction, modeling

Hello I have dataframe that looks like the below. The data is basically capacity information of a cluster system. This is like a small sample of it.
You may notice that the **days_to_full** column fluctuates a lot within a span of 20 days. The **Threshold_date** column is date when the disk will be full based on adding the **days_to_full** to the **Datetime** column.

If I were to build a model that could oversee the high fluctuations in the threshold_date and notify me only when the growth is fairly linear or basically when the growth is real. How would I do that?
I would like to know at least 90 to 100 days in advance that I could be going full for real. But such fluctuations could give me wrong predications and cause panic for no reason.

I've been trying to read a lot of articles but unable to identify what (mathematical)model using python would help me make better estimations.

Appreciate if some one could explain why you suggest a model when you suggest it and what are the parameters that could be looked at to make it as optimal in predication as possible. Thanks in advance!

```
cluster_name   region   Datetime    total_data_capacity used_data_capacity  available_data_capacity days_to_full    Threshold_date
cluster01      lon      2021-03-02  29990.745869        23540.127364        6450.618505             219.000000      2021-11-14
cluster01      lon      2021-03-03  29990.745869        23555.783363        6434.962505             219.000000      2021-11-14
cluster01      lon      2021-03-04  29990.745869        23572.610517        6418.135352             219.833333      2021-11-14
cluster01      lon      2021-03-05  29990.745869        23589.994672        6400.751197             220.000000      2021-11-15
cluster01      lon      2021-03-06  29990.745869        23608.169950        6382.575918             220.000000      2021-11-15
cluster01      lon      2021-03-07  29990.745869        23612.727373        6378.018496             220.000000      2021-11-15
cluster01      lon      2021-03-08  29990.745869        23621.996424        6368.749444             220.000000      2021-11-15
cluster01      lon      2021-03-09  29990.745869        23642.840187        6347.905682             926.285714      2023-10-22
cluster01      lon      2021-03-10  29990.745869        23663.032472        6327.713397             1044.000000     2024-02-17
cluster01      lon      2021-03-11  29990.745869        23682.244640        6308.501229             1004.833333     2024-01-08
cluster01      lon      2021-03-12  29990.745869        23703.716183        6287.029686             997.000000      2024-01-01
cluster01      lon      2021-03-13  29990.745869        23723.670334        6267.075534             997.000000      2024-01-01
cluster01      lon      2021-03-14  29990.745869        23726.441732        6264.304136             997.000000      2024-01-01
cluster01      lon      2021-03-15  29990.745869        23638.685020        6352.060849             997.000000      2024-01-01
cluster01      lon      2021-03-16  29990.745869        23607.307080        6383.438789             1022.000000     2024-01-26
cluster01      lon      2021-03-17  29990.745869        23649.954446        6340.791423             1027.000000     2024-01-31
cluster01      lon      2021-03-18  29990.745869        23694.870332        6295.875536             991.545455      2023-12-26
cluster01      lon      2021-03-19  29990.745869        23739.976639        6250.769230             988.000000      2023-12-23
```

Comment: How are you calculating days till full?

Comment: @forgetso The system is doing it for me. Well, basically it is "Available storage"/daily-growth-rate = Days_to_full

Comment: I would use a moving average of  `days_to_full` so that you get the average of the last 10 (or so) days. That way, the spikes will disappear and you could use a simple linear regression/prediction.

Comment: @RaJa There are times when there is high influx of data into the system and sometimes its flushed out. So threshold date sometime shows it could fill within this year and suddenly when the consumption drops it shows 2 years to be full. The concern is these rapid changes aren't worth making some one panic if the prediction is false. So not sure if 10 days avg will help or in other words. How do I identify the effective number of days to average the value?

Comment: Get a longer sample and plot different sizes of moving average.

Comment: Make predictions from different averaging windows. Plot how often a certain prediction (aka Threshold date) occurs and select your desired confidence interval. Then you know what your lowest averaging window should be.

Answer (score 1):

To make such predictions you need a model of how future values of `available_data_capacity` depend on its values in the past (or past values of other available variables). As you suggest yourself, a reasonable assumption to start with would be a linear dependency (plus zero-mean noise). In that case you would fit a linear model to the data up to the present, and use the slope and intercept to extrapolate into the future, to see if the predicted values of `available_data_capacity` reach zero within your desired timespan.

You also mention that there are outliers that may interfere with the prediction. In that case you could opt for [robust linear regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robust_regression), which is designed to deal (among other things) with outliers. Methods for this are readily available in python, e.g. [scipy.stats.siegelslopes](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.siegelslopes.html).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It seems to make sense to begin with. I will have to try this out and happen to notice there is something called robustpolyfit and the claim it is for fitting robust linear models to small datasets (10 - 20 datapoints) and an order of magnitude faster for larger datasets. Thanks for opening this door. Will read more into it.